# Rest service for books made with php and json

Tags: php, json, rest

Hi i was following a tutorial that is very helpful for my project but I cant figure out what is the error :
Here is the code for index.php in the folder restClient:
`first the html code :`

### ENTER BOOK :

` ...
and the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    //Resourse Address        
    $url = "http://localhost/jelenavulesevic3i4domaci/rest/$name";

    //Send request to Resourse        
    $client = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    //get response from resource
    $response = curl_exec($client);

    //echo $response;

    //decode        
    $result = json_decode($response);

    echo $result->data; //THIS WONT WORK

}
```

and i have a different index.php in a rest folder :

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
include ("function.php");
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){


$name = $_GET['name'];
    $price = get_price($name);

    if(empty($price))
        deliver_response(200, "Book Not Found", NULL);
    else
        deliver_response(200, "Book Found", $price);
}else{
    deliver_response(400, "Invalid Request", NULL);
}

function deliver_response($status, $status_message, $data){
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

    $response['status'] = $status;
    $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
    $response['data'] = $data;

    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

and the function.php in the  folder rest which goes like this :

```
function get_price($find){
    $books = array(
        "java" => 299,
        "c" => 343,
        "php" => 223
    );

    foreach($books as $book=>$price){
        if($book == $find)
        {
            return $price;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My error is at a line in index.php for the client where it says :
 echo $result->data;

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: echo $result->data wont work ir your data is an array. Best wayr to figure out what is worng is to dump the entire sesponse and see what you are getting: var_dump($response). whis should be a json string, if it's not, the problem is your api endpoint

Comment: what you get with `var_dump($result );exit` in your curl call ?

Comment: i am not getting a json string with var dump any idea what should i fix to get the price of the book i entered in search